# Debian Networking Issues

Tags: debian, networking

I recently installed Debian Wheezy (gnome) on my ThinkPad T60. It was going well, until about 2 days ago when suddenly my machine stopped connecting to the web.

I can connect to my router, I can ping my router and get a response, but if I ping, say, google or something, then it automatically responds:

```
ping: unknown host google.com
```

I have no idea what's wrong with it, so here's a summary of what I've done network-wise recently:

- Installed Tor
- Removed Tor
- Installed OpenVPN and OpenConnect, as well as PPTP (for network manager)
- Added a VPN to my networks list (which is disabled by default)

Hopefully some of this information will be useful for solving the problem. I'd be happy to carry out any instructions you need for gathering information on the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you ping 8.8.8.8, or 8.8.4.4?

those are the ip addresses of Google's public DNS servers.

The `unknown host` error you post indicates at least a host name resolution error, not necessarily a network error.

Then, check `/etc/resolv.conf` and see if your dns servers are there.

- If the entries are there:

  - check your `default route`.
- If the entries are **not** there:

  - create a working resolv.conf, with the right name servers.

If your network configuration and your DNS configuration are both correct, then start at layer 1 and work your way up.  Is the NIC ok?  Do you have link?  Does your switch or router show link as well?  Any duplex or speed mismatches?

After that check layer 2.  Does your router have your PC in it's ARP table? etc.

Do you have another laptop or PC that you can plug into the same network path, and validate that the problem is with the Thinkpad?

Comment: Yes, just before I received this answer, I had discovered that it's a DNS problem. I'm using my other laptop over this same network right now. I'm just not quite sure how to solve dns issues. my resolv.conf is all but blank, with just a comment at the top saying "Generated by NetworkManager".

Comment: Problem solved! I added two nameservers to the /etc/resolv.conf file, and now it all works fine. Thanks!